# Selecting records from two tables

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following snippet code:

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from books");
 ResultSetMetaData resMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
 int nCols = resMetaData.getColumnCount();
 for (int kCol = 1; kCol <= nCols; kCol++) {
    System.out.println(resMetaData.getColumnName(kCol));
 }
 while (rs.next()) {
    for (int kCol = 1; kCol <= nCols; kCol++) {
       String s = null;
       if (kCol == nCols){
        Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select category_name from categories where category_id = " + rs.getString(kCol));
        s = rs1.getString(2);
    }
    else{
        s = rs.getString(kCol);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
   }
 }
```

In my data base I have two tables: *books* and *categories*. In both table I have a column *category_id*. The code selects records from the table *books*. The *category_id* from this table matches the *category_id* from table *categories*. In this table I have one more row: category_name. I want that the app to write the name from the *category_name* that matches the category_id in table books. I tried but I failed. So, could you give me any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: You should get familiar with Joins https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: `SELECT books.book_name, books.category_id, categoty.category_name
FROM books LEFT JOIN  categories  
ON books.category_id  = categories.category_id`

Comment: You can do it using SQL JOIN. Replace your query with a query similar to above one see if it can solve your problem.

Comment: I would like to ask : there is any possibility to retrieve the value directly from rs1 (i.e. by executing query in smtm1 ) ?